# What structure is used for storing CONTEXT, CTXCAT and CTXRULE Oracle text indexes?

Tags: oracle, index

AFAIK there are three major structure types used for storing Oracle index data: B-tree, R-tree and Bitmap. All indexes use one of these structures. However, not sure about CONTEXT, CTXCAT and CTXRULE Oracle text indexes...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation covers this thoroughly.

See [this link](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm) for more detail.